# Color the Screen in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I've been working on an operating system for some time now, written in assembly. Everything has been running fine so far except one thing. I'm trying to quickly fill the screen with a background color, instead of looping through each pixel and changing its color(which takes quite a while). Is there any code capable of doing such a task?

Comment: What kind of assembly are you coding? x86, MIPS, or something else?

Comment: That's the problem with creating your own operating system, nobody can help you unless they know your OS.  You'll have to do this the Linus way, publish your code and get others to help you implement it.

Comment: The problem is I'm only familiar with Windows. I've never touched Linux in my life!

Comment: Oh misread the question. Didn't realise you were making your own OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question "How to color screen" in context "I've been working on an operating system"... Overwrite the framebuffer with desired color.

How to achieve this depends on if you're working in real mode or protected mode. For example in real mode with graphics mode 13h, you can access the framebuffer at address A000h. For information about graphics in protected mode see [this link at osdev.org wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Drawing_In_Protected_Mode).